# Serrated vs flat-edge knives

Tags: knives

Each has their purpose, I'm sure. So for what activities is each better? When would I use one over the other? What about half-serrated blades?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Flat-edge` knives are the best choice for wilderness and campsite activities. A lot of times you have to use beating stick to split wood and that will dull out any serration you might have anywhere on the knife.

`Serrated` knives (and partially serrated) come in handy in suburban environment where you have to cut man made materials like plastic and rubber. They are also good in self-defense since they go through clothing better than straight edge (but there are different options on the self defense aspect of it).

Comment: Serrated are also a lot more difficult to keep sharp.

Comment: Let me quantify that then, they are much more difficult to sharpen if all you have is a whetstone.

Comment: Serrated knives are better for cutting climbing or sailing ropes.